# Дешифровка ecryptfs

Tags: linux, файлы

Мне нужно восстановить файлы из `/home/.ecryptfs/user` или каким-то образом увидеть их наличие и скопировать куда-то.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно загрузится с LiveCD и установить Ecryptfs:

```
sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils
```

Затем смонтируйте ваш диск:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Потом сделаем туда chroot:

```
sudo chroot /mnt/ /bin/bash
```

Команда Chroot (change root) сменит корневой каталог на указанный вами и запустит команду приведенную следующей. Команда sudo не потребует ввода пароля, потому что при запуске с LiveCD пользователи пароля не имеют, и вы переключитесь на режим пользователя root в установленной системе и запустите оболочку bash. Итак, вы вошли в смонтированную систему с правами root, далее монтируем ваш домашний каталог:

```
sudo mount -t ecryptfs /home/user_name/.Private /home/user_name/Private
```

где user_name — это ваш пользователь.

Выйдите из chroot нажатием клавиш Ctrl+D, и копируйте ваши файлы из каталога /mnt/home/user_name/Private

Должно получится, если помните пароль пользователя и не меняли его после установки.

---

Погуглил немного, вот ещё вариант так точно получится:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
ubuntu@ubuntu$ sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
ubuntu@ubuntu$ sudo mount -o bind /dev/shm /mnt/dev/shm
ubuntu@ubuntu$ sudo mount -o bind /proc /mnt/proc
ubuntu@ubuntu$ sudo mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys
ubuntu@ubuntu$ sudo chroot /mnt
root@ubuntu$ su - kirkland
kirkland@ubuntu$ ecryptfs-mount-private
kirkland@ubuntu$ cd $HOME
kirkland@ubuntu$ ls
```

kirkland — это имя пользователя

/dev/sda1 — это раздел на котором лежит ваш home

---

Ещё погуглил, оказалось всё очень просто, начиная с релиза Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty Narwhal) этот процесс автоматизирован:

1. Запускаем Ubuntu 11.04 LiveCD
2. Монтируем раздел
3. Даем команду 'sudo ecryptfs-recover-private' она прошуршит, найдет ваш раздел и предложит смонтировать, от вас только ввести пароль.
4. Запускаем 'sudo nautilus' и копируем куда хотим